# Bash: log stdout and stderr while preserving order and provenance

Tags: bash, logging, io-redirection

It's fairly simple to log both the stdout and the stderr of a command to a log file:

```
./foo.sh &> log.txt
```

The problem is that when inspecting the log file, one doesn't know anymore which line was coming from which stream. This could be fixed by redirecting stdout and stderr to two separate files, but then the chronology and interleaving of the output is lost.

An other solution would be to redirect to three files. One with the stdout, one with the stderr, and one with both combined. Something like:

```
./foo.sh 2> >(tee stderr | tee -a combined) 1> >(tee stdout | tee -a combined)
```

But that is not be very elegant to have so many files (and this command still dumps a copy of the output on the shell).

I found an interesting bash function that would color only stderr messages in red:

```
color()(set -o pipefail;"$@" 2>&1>&3|sed $'s,.*,\e[31m&\e[m,'>&2)3>&1
```

but it doesn't preserve the order of the output and the result is unreadable in a text editor. Given the following program for `foo.sh`:

```
for i in 1 2; do
   for j in 1 2; do
     printf '%s\n' "out $i"
   done
   for k in 1 2; do
     printf '%s\n' "err $i" >&2
   done
done
```

Running `color ./foo.sh` produces:

```
out 1
out 1
out 2
out 2
[31merr 1[m
[31merr 1[m
[31merr 2[m
[31merr 2[m
```

How could one easily end up with something such as this in a single log file ?

```
@| out 1
@| out 1
$| err 1
$| err 1
@| out 2
@| out 2
$| err 2
$| err 2
```

Comment: Have you considered [logging to syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger)?

Comment: I don't see how that could help in distinguishing the stdout and stderr of a command ?

Comment: The idea is to log whatever message you want logged directly to syslog with the appropriate log level, and not bother with STDOUT and STDERR. If that's not applicable in your case, might something like this do: `command 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /' >>out.txt) >>out.txt`?

Comment: There is no specific message I am expecting. I just want to log the result of a command. No, unfortunately that `sed` command doesn't do as I explained in my question since it doesn't preserve the order.

Comment: Output buffering is inherently part of how the standard streams operate. There is no way to guarantee that they will spill onto your display or into a file in a particular order. This is a very common FAQ.

Comment: @tripleee Sure, if the program is outputting concurrently on both streams, there is a random component. But I'd be already very happy with an approximate solution that pools both streams every 50 ms or so.

Comment: The standard seolution is to make both streams unbuffered. However, this can have severe performance penalties. Again, this is a very common question; it is not hard to find answers suggesting this workaround and explaining it in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply BTW - I have no idea why this very old question popped up in my stream yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for `script`
it records both stdout, stderr and the commands...it starts a new shell in which it records everything (or use `-c _cmd_`)

```
 $ script tx1
```

your `color()` function breaks order because `sed` is buffering...

Comment: This doesn't maintain provenance (that is, history on which of stdout or stderr each line came from).

Answer (score 2):

How about redirecting stderr to ./tmperr and stdout to ./tmpout, now run two scripts in the background that each continuously read a single line from tmperr or tmpout and then remove that line?  This is obviously less than ideal, but if there is a decent delay in the actual foo.sh script, this should work out.

Comment: Preserving order only when there aren't race conditions is hardly "preserving order".