# Traceback messing up with print Python | order of print changing randomly

Tags: python, printing, traceback

`print` and `traceback` are messing up, even though `print` should happen before, `traceback` is printed above, in between and below.

```
try:
    zerrr()    
except Exception as e:
    error_json, raise_error, throw = excHandler(e, throw=False)
    # print(type(k))
    if throw:
        raise Exception(raise_error)

    error_dict = json.loads(error_json)
    print(error_dict)

try:
    typerr()    
except Exception as e:
    error_json, raise_error, throw = excHandler(e, throw=True)
    # print(type(k))
    if throw:
        # raise Exception(raise_error)
        traceback.print_exc()    
    error_dict = json.loads(error_json)
    # print(error_dict)
finally:
    # Necessary calls
    musthappen()
```

**First Run Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
{'1515142630.125066': {'Line': 48, 'Error_call': "'return 1/0'", 'File': 'C:/Users/ankit.chouksey/Mariott/Pys/exclog.py', 'Error': ['ZeroDivisionError: division by zero\n'], 'Function': 'zerrr'}}
  File "C:/Users/ankit.chouksey/Mariott/Pys/exclog.py", line 69, in <module>
This is always happening irrespective of exceptions
    typerr()
  File "C:/Users/ankit.chouksey/Mariott/Pys/exclog.py", line 51, in typerr
    return 1+'a'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

**First Run:**
Dictionary was to print before traceback but it's being printed inside.
Similarly the statement "This is always happening irrespective of exceptions" was to print after traceback but it's printing in between.

**Second Run Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
{'1515143476.309911': {'Line': 48, 'Error': ['ZeroDivisionError: division by zero\n'], 'Function': 'zerrr', 'Error_call': "'return 1/0'", 'File': 'C:/Users/ankit.chouksey/Mariott/Pys/exclog.py'}}
This is always happening irrespective of exceptions
  File "C:/Users/ankit.chouksey/Mariott/Pys/exclog.py", line 69, in <module>
    typerr()
  File "C:/Users/ankit.chouksey/Mariott/Pys/exclog.py", line 51, in typerr
    return 1+'a'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

**Second Run:**
Both prints are together but inside traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: log stdout and stderr while preserving order and provenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684764/bash-log-stdout-and-stderr-while-preserving-order-and-provenance)

Comment: This is a very common FAQ and in no way specific to Python. Standard output and standard error are not guaranteed to be displayed in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a similar code on my computer.
When testing it in `terminal`, the output is always normal and expected.
However when testing in `IDE(PyCharm)`, the output is messing up just as what you have said.
**So are you testing your code in an `IDE`?**
And I think the answer **might** depend on the IDE you are using.(The IDE might pushing messages to `stdout` in multithreads/multiprocessings?**(NOT SURE)**)

Comment: yes, I am using PyCharm. Maybe it's because of PyCharm's threading methods.

Answer (score 0):

No clue why, but PyCharm chooses to make their output insanely confusing and put tracebacks randomly scattered with your print statements. To fix , try going to your run configuration (the wrench):

[image]

Then select "Emulate terminal output in console"

[image]